# How to fetch Contentful entries using only url insted of entry-id using ruby on rails?

Tags: contentful

///This is my code

@blog = Blog.locale("en-US").find(params[:aci])

///I want to fetch entries using page_url instead of params[:aci] which is entry ID.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Contentful DevRel here.

Assuming that by `page_url` you mean something like a `slug` value, you can use [the Ruby gem](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/ruby/tutorials/getting-started-with-contentful-and-ruby/) and fetch entries for a specific url/slug like so.

```
require 'contentful'

client = Contentful::Client.new(
  space: '<space_id>',
  access_token: '<content_delivery_api_key>',
  environment: 'master',  # Optional - defaults to 'master'.
  dynamic_entries: :auto  # Enables Content Type caching.
)

entries = client.entries('fields.slug' => 'my-first-post')
```